# Force breadcrumbs items not breaking to another line when viewport is narrow

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, breadcrumbs

I am trying to create breadcrumbs that has arrow look. This is the design.

*Please, note the text is in more lines inside each breadcrumb item, when too long.*

[image]

We can assume there will always be maximum 4 breadcrums items:

- Home
- First category
- Dots (for the case of more categories)
- Last category

I have a solution, but since the design is responsive, the solution **doesn't work at all for narrow viewports**. When the text inside breadcrumb item is too long, it kept going in one line, making the breadcrumb item long. Then, when the viewport gets narrow, whole breadcrumb item is breaking into a new line. WRONG!

I use Bootstrap.

Any idea how to solve this?

**Here goes fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/aeoLcm1m/

HTML:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb noppadinglr">
  <li><a href="#" class="home"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Vehicles</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="dots">...</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1989 VW Westfalia Vanagon</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.breadcrumb {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: 0px transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  background: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.breadcrumb .home {
  background: #d3d3d3 url(img/ico/ico-house.png) right center no-repeat;
  width: 40px;
  height: 48px;
  display: block;
}
.breadcrumb img {
  width: 75%;
  max-height: 18px;
}
.breadcrumb .dots {
  padding: 18px 0 10px 20px;
}
.breadcrumb li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
.breadcrumb li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 18px 0 10px 40px;
  background: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.breadcrumb li a::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent lightgrey;
  border-width: 50px 0px 50px 30px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.breadcrumb li a::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent blue;
  border-width: 50px 0px 50px 30px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.breadcrumb li:first-child a {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.breadcrumb li:last-child a {
  background: lightblue !important;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
.breadcrumb li:last-child a:after {
  border-left-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the white-space property for the links directly

```
.breadcrumbs li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: you don't need `float: left;` and `display: inline-block;` for `li` and `a`. only one or the other. maybe that causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the breadcrumb behaving a you describe, although you may want to tweak this further. Quite a few changes have been made (all to CSS) so I'll try to explain the main ones that effect the layout.

```
.breadcrumb {
    height: 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

`font-size: 0;` is to remove any whitespace between the `li`.

```
.breadcrumb .dots {
    padding: 18px 0 10px 20px;
}
```

Was removed entirely as the padding is no longer necessary.

```
.breadcrumb li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: lightgrey;
    height: 48px;
    max-width: 30%;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

`float: left;` was removed as you can't have it and `display: inline-block;` at the same time (floating makes the element `display: block;`). `padding: 0 0 0 40px;` has been moved from the `a` to the `li` and the top and bottom padding removed to allow the text to take up the desired space. `vertical-align: middle;` is added to vertically align the `li` which are now set to `display: inline-block;`. `font-size: 12px;` is set to override the setting on the `ul`.

```
.breadcrumb li:after {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This is added to vertically align the text in the `a`s.

```
.breadcrumb li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: lightgrey;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

`padding` is removed as the text is now vertically aligned, `float` also removed for the reasons explained above.

```
.breadcrumb li:last-child {
    background: lightblue !important;
}
```

`background-color` applied to `li` as the `a` may not take up the full height.

```
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
    content: "";   
    display: none;
}
```

This was added to hide pseudo element created by the imported stylesheet.

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8468x3a/2/)